# pythonで ValueError: not enough values to unpack というエラーが出てしまう

Tags: python

画像検出のプログラムで輪郭を抽出したく、参考書をもとにかいているのですが

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

というエラーが出てしまいわかりません。変数と要素の数が一致しないというものらしいのですが、いろいろ試してみたものの解決できませんでした。教えてくださる方がいらっしゃいましたら教えてください。

```
# 輪郭を抽出
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img_bgr=cv2.imread('earth15_02.jpg')
img_gray=cv2.cvtColor(img_bgr,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
retval,thresh=cv2.threshold(img_gray,88,255,0)
img,contours,hierarchy=cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

result_img=cv2.drawContours(img,contours,-1,(0,0,255),3)

#
plt.imshow(result_img);
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

これらの記事が当てはまるでしょう。
[pythonで発生したValueError: not enough values to unpackの解決](https://teratail.com/questions/194500)
[[OpenCV] ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)](https://qiita.com/rareshana/items/6a2f5e7396f28f6eee49)

2つ目の記事に沿って`img,contours,hierarchy=cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)`の先頭の`img`を削除すればその行は動作しますが、質問記事のソースでは直後に`img`をパラメータとして使っているので、またそこでエラーになります。

Python, OpenCV, matplotlib の各版数を参考書で使っているものに合わせるか、新しい版数の仕様に合わせて参考書のソースを書き換える必要があるでしょう。

ちなみにこの記事あたりが新しい版数に対応していそうです。
参考書の内容と細かく対比できるとも限りませんが、何かの足しに。
[OpenCVで画像から輪郭検出の基本（findContours関数あたり）](https://kitakantech.com/opencv-findcontours/)